# Dynamics AX 7 Recurring File (folder) integration

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, d3fo

I am trying to import file from a 3rd party application. I followed the link to create a recurring data job to import the file: 
[Recurring integrations](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/recurring-integrations/)

For client application i downloaded a GitHub project: 
[Dynamics AX Integration samples and demos](https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration)

I am receiving an error:

Failure processing file: CustGroupExp-Customer groups.XML.Exception : AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'b109ce07-67b6-434f-9aee-b5294292e306'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Can anybody tell me what might be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created an application ID in Microsoft Azure Active Directory (AAD)  and gave it appropriate permission to Dynamics 365 for Operations as mentioned here https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/recurring-integrations/#authorization-for-the-integration-rest-api

Comment: If you have access to below course there is demo available there.  https://mbspartner.microsoft.com/AX/CourseModules/1334

Comment: Yes. I have created an application ID  in Microsoft Azure Active Directory (AAD) and give it appropriate permission. I added the application on Azure Active Directory with the Redirect Uri: https://usncax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com/en/api/connector/enqueue// <activity ID> entity = <My Entity>

Comment: "Active directory resource"  URI should not have trailing slash and should be in all lowercase as per https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/troubleshooting-service-authentication/   Also try http://blah.winsmarts.com/2015-4-Azure_AD_OAuth2_implicit_grant.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I was giving wrong Aad Tenant and Azure Auth Endpoint values in App.config.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Pradeep's comment regarding the application ID...

You will have to go to the classic (old) azure portal [here](https://manage.windowsazure.com) and authorize your application. On the left hand side, scroll down and choose the Active Directory option, select the AD tenant, then go to Applications at the top of the tenant landing page. On the Applications page click "Add+" at the bottom of the screen.

You will be shown a selection on what type of application to add, you likely want to choose "Add an application my organization is developing". Name it, select the correct type, and click next. The next screen asks for a redirect uri, this is not an optional field **but** if you don't have a specific URI in mind just put in some valid html (for example I use: https://no.redirect)

Once the application has been setup, select your newly created application and go to Configure. Remember to add Dynamics AX to the permissions at the bottom of this page (if req'd). Also note that on this screen is your newly created application ID (Client ID) that is now authorized for use in this tenant.

[image]

[image]